# Chrome not saving cookies at all

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I am going crazy, I have spent this whole week trying to find out why chrome keeps on deleting cookies. I am using Windows 7 SP1 64x on a Dell studio 1737. Its an old system but is actually quite fast and well at running games for my needs. After not knowing why chrome is signing me out of all my accounts, I install cookiebro extension. Every time I close chrome, they get deleted. I looked all over the internet for a solution but nothing worked. I then discovered there isn't even a folder for cookies in C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default. I tried to create a folder named "Cookies" to see if that was the case but chrome keeps deleting the folder each time I close it. I have no cleaning or antivirus software. I actually think this happened after an update on windows, dobut it may be it tho. I am lost and have no clue. Loging in everytime using the computer is a nightmare. Any help is great. Thanks.